# hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin generates insert + update instead of single insert on adding a new entity

Tags: hibernate

I have a simple entity, something like that:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@NotEmpty
private String name;

@NotNull
@Basic(fetch = LAZY)
@Column(columnDefinition = "BYTEA")
private byte[] content;

}
```

When I save this entity using spring-data-jpa repository I'm getting single insert like this:

```
insert 
into
    user
    (content, name, id) 
values
    (?, ?, ?)
```

But I need to load content field lazily, so I've added maven plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm.tooling</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
             <configuration>
                 <failOnError>true</failOnError>                   <enableLazyInitialization>true</enableLazyInitialization>
             </configuration>
             <goals>
                 <goal>enhance</goal>
             </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And now I have 2 SQL statements instead of 1:

```
Hibernate: 
insert 
into
    user
    (content, name, id) 
values
    (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
update
    user
set
    content=?,
    name=?,
where
    id=?
```

Could someone explain why does it happen?

**Update:** Before commit on flush event is thrown. The difference is in DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.mightBeDirty method.

When plugin is enabled dirtyProperties = persister.resolveAttributeIndexes( ( (SelfDirtinessTracker) entity ).$$_hibernate_getDirtyAttributes() ); returns all properties, when plugin is disabled all properties are null and in first case hibernate decides to execute update statement, in the second case nothing to update.

Method $$_hibernate_getDirtyAttributes() is created in EntityEnhancer and looks like this:

```
public boolean $$_hibernate_getDirtyAttributes() { 
    return ($$_hibernate_tracker != null && !$$_hibernate_tracker.isEmpty()) || $$_hibernate_areCollectionFieldsDirty;" 
}
```

$$_hibernate_tracker field contains all fields entity fields inside, so it's not null or empty.

Looks like these properties should be cleaned up after persist or something added it.

$$_hibernate_trackChange is not called, that means these properties left after persist. I suppose something should clean it up.

Only in postUpdate these properties are cleaned.

Answer (score 1):

In my high-performance-java-persistence GitHub repository, you can find the [`LazyAttributeWithMultipleEntitiesTest`](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence/blob/c52cd8962ad5238c4ac0472a495b83e8d3bb956c/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/book/hpjp/hibernate/fetching/LazyAttributeWithMultipleEntitiesTest.java).

After enabling the `enableLazyInitialization` Hibernate enhance property and persisting these entities:

```
Attachment book = new Attachment();
book.setName("High-Performance Java Persistence");
book.setMediaType(MediaType.PDF);
book.setContent(Files.readAllBytes(bookFilePath));
entityManager.persist(book);

Attachment video = new Attachment();
video.setName("High-Performance Hibernate");
video.setMediaType(MediaType.MPEG_VIDEO);
video.setContent(Files.readAllBytes(videoFilePath));
entityManager.persist(video);
```

Hibernate generates the following INSERT statements:

```
Query:["select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update"], Params:[()]
Query:["update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?"], Params:[(2, 1)]
Query:["select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence for update"], Params:[()]
Query:["update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?"], Params:[(3, 2)]

Query:["insert into attachment (media_type, name, content, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)"], Params:[(20, High-Performance Java Persistence, [60, 63, 120, 109, 108, 32, 118, 101, 114, 115, 105, 111, 110, 61, 34, 49, 46, 48, 34, 32, 101, 110, 99, 111, 100, 105, 110, 103, 61, 34, 85, 84, 70, 45, 56, 34, 63, 62, 10, 60, 101, 104, 99, 97, 99, 104, 101, 32, 120, 109, 108, 110, 115, 58, 120, 115, 105, 61, 34, 104, 116, 116, 112, 58, 47, 47, 119, 119, 119, 46, 119, 51, 46, 111, 114, 103, 47, 50, 48, 48, 49, 47, 88, 77, 76, 83, 99, 104, 101, 109, 97, 45, 105, 110, 115, 116, 97, 110, 99, 101, 34, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 120, 115, 105, 58, 110, 111, 78, 97, 109, 101, 115, 112, 97, 99, 101, 83, 99, 104, 101, 109, 97, 76, 111, 99, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 61, 34, 101, 104, 99, 97, 99, 104, 101, 46, 120, 115, 100, 34, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 117, 112, 100, 97, 116, 101, 67, 104, 101, 99, 107, 61, 34, 116, 114, 117, 101, 34, 32, 109, 111, 110, 105, 116, 111, 114, 105, 110, 103, 61, 34, 97, 117, 116, 111, 100, 101, 116, 101, 99, 116, 34, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 100, 121, 110, 97, 109, 105, 99, 67, 111, 110, 102, 105, 103, 61, 34, 116, 114, 117, 101, 34, 62, 10, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 60, 100, 101, 102, 97, 117, 108, 116, 67, 97, 99, 104, 101, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 109, 97, 120, 69, 108, 101, 109, 101, 110, 116, 115, 73, 110, 77, 101, 109, 111, 114, 121, 61, 34, 49, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 34, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 101, 116, 101, 114, 110, 97, 108, 61, 34, 116, 114, 117, 101, 34, 62, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 60, 112, 101, 114, 115, 105, 115, 116, 101, 110, 99, 101, 32, 115, 116, 114, 97, 116, 101, 103, 121, 61, 34, 110, 111, 110, 101, 34, 47, 62, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 60, 47, 100, 101, 102, 97, 117, 108, 116, 67, 97, 99, 104, 101, 62, 10, 60, 47, 101, 104, 99, 97, 99, 104, 101, 62, 10], 1)]
Query:["insert into attachment (media_type, name, content, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)"], Params:[(19, High-Performance Hibernate, [35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 13, 10, 35, 32, 80, 54, 83, 112, 121, 32, 79, 112, 116, 105, 111, 110, 115, 32, 70, 105, 108, 101, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 35, 13, 10, 35, 32, 83, 101, 101, 32, 100, 111, 99, 117, 109, 101, 110, 116, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 32, 102, 111, 114, 32, 100, 101, 116, 97, 105, 108, 101, 100, 32, 105, 110, 115, 116, 114, 117, 99, 116, 105, 111, 110, 115, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 35, 13, 10, 35, 32, 104, 116, 116, 112, 58, 47, 47, 112, 54, 115, 112, 121, 46, 103, 105, 116, 104, 117, 98, 46, 105, 111, 47, 112, 54, 115, 112, 121, 47, 50, 46, 48, 47, 99, 111, 110, 102, 105, 103, 97, 110, 100, 117, 115, 97, 103, 101, 46, 104, 116, 109, 108, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 35, 13, 10, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 13, 10, 13, 10, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 13, 10, 35, 32, 77, 79, 68, 85, 76, 69, 83, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 35, 13, 10, 35, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 35, 13, 10, 35, 32, 77, 111, 100, 117, 108, 101, 32, 108, 105, 115, 116, 32, 97, 100, 97, 112, 116, 115, 32, 116, 104, 101, 32, 109, 111, 100, 117, 108, 97, 114, 32, 102, 117, 110, 99, 116, 105, 111, 110, 97, 108, 105, 116, 121, 32, 111, 102, 32, 80, 54, 83, 112, 121, 46, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 35, 13, 10, 35, 32, 79, 110, 108, 121, 32, 109, 111, 100, 117, 108, 101, 115, 32, 108, 105, 115, 116, 101, 100, 32, 97, 114, 101, 32, 97, 99, 116, 105, 118, 101, 46, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 35, 13, 10, 35, 32, 40, 100, 101, 102, 97, 117, 108, 116, 32, 105, 115, 32, 99, 111, 109, 46, 112, 54, 115, 112, 121, 46, 101, 110, 103, 105, 110, 101, 46, 108, 111, 103, 103, 105, 110, 103, 46, 80, 54, 76, 111, 103, 70, 97, 99, 116, 111, 114, 121, 32, 97, 110, 100, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 35, 13, 10, 35, 32, 99, 111, 109, 46, 112, 54, 115, 112, 121, 46, 101, 110, 103, 105, 110, 101, 46, 115, 112, 121, 46, 80, 54, 83, 112, 121, 70, 97, 99, 116, 111, 114, 121, 41, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 35, 13, 10, 35, 32, 80, 108, 101, 97, 115, 101, 32, 110, 111, 116, 101, 32, 116, 104, 97, 116, 32, 116, 104, 101, 32, 99, 111, 114, 101, 32, 109, 111, 100, 117, 108, 101, 32, 40, 80, 54, 83, 112, 121, 70, 97, 99, 116, 111, 114, 121, 41, 32, 99, 97, 110, 39, 116, 32, 98, 101, 32, 32, 32, 35, 13, 10, 35, 32, 100, 101, 97, 99, 116, 105, 118, 97, 116, 101, 100, 46, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 35, 13, 10, 35, 32, 85, 110, 108, 105, 107, 101, 32, 116, 104, 101, 32, 111, 116, 104, 101, 114, 32, 112, 114, 111, 112, 101, 114, 116, 105, 101, 115, 44, 32, 97, 99, 116, 105, 118, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 32, 111, 102, 32, 116, 104, 101, 32, 99, 104, 97, 110, 103, 101, 115, 32, 111, 110, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 35, 13, 10, 35, 32, 116, 104, 105, 115, 32, 111, 110, 101, 32, 114, 101, 113, 117, 105, 114, 101, 115, 32, 114, 101, 108, 111, 97, 100, 46, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 35, 13, 10, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 13, 10, 109, 111, 100, 117, 108, 101, 108, 105, 115, 116, 61, 99, 111, 109, 46, 112, 54, 115, 112, 121, 46, 101, 110, 103, 105, 110, 101, 46, 115, 112, 121, 46, 80, 54, 83, 112, 121, 70, 97, 99, 116, 111, 114, 121, 44, 99, 111, 109, 46, 112, 54, 115, 112, 121, 46, 101, 110, 103, 105, 110, 101, 46, 108, 111, 103, 103, 105, 110, 103, 46, 80, 54, 76, 111, 103, 70, 97, 99, 116, 111, 114, 121, 44, 99, 111, 109, 46, 112, 54, 115, 112, 121, 46, 101, 110, 103, 105, 110, 101, 46, 111, 117, 116, 97, 103, 101, 46, 80, 54, 79, 117, 116, 97, 103, 101, 70, 97, 99, 116, 111, 114, 121, 13, 10, 13, 10, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 13, 10, 35, 32, 67, 79, 82, 69, 32, 40, 80, 54, 83, 80, 89, 41, 32, 80, 82, 79, 80, 69, 82, 84, 73, 69, 83, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 35, 13, 10, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 13, 10, 13, 10, 35, 32, 65, 32, 99, 111, 109, 109, 97, 32, 115, 101, 112, 97, 114, 97, 116, 101, 100, 32, 108, 105, 115, 116, 32, 111, 102, 32, 74, 68, 66, 67, 32, 100, 114, 105, 118, 101, 114, 115, 32, 116, 111, 32, 108, 111, 97, 100, 32, 97, 110, 100, 32, 114, 101, 103, 105, 115, 116, 101, 114, 46, 13, 10, 35, 32, 40, 100, 101, 102, 97, 117, 108, 116, 32, 105, 115, 32, 101, 109, 112, 116, 121, 41, 13, 10, 35, 13, 10, 35, 32, 78, 111, 116, 101, 58, 32, 84, 104, 105, 115, 32, 105, 115, 32, 110, 111, 114, 109, 97, 108, 108, 121, 32, 111, 110, 108, 121, 32, 110, 101, 101, 100, 101, 100, 32, 119, 104, 101, 110, 32, 117, 115, 105, 110, 103, 32, 80, 54, 83, 112, 121, 32, 105, 110, 32, 97, 110, 13, 10, 35, 32, 97, 112, 112, 108, 105, 99, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 32, 115, 101, 114, 118, 101, 114, 32, 101, 110, 118, 105, 114, 111, 110, 109, 101, 110, 116, 32, 119, 105, 116, 104, 32, 97, 32, 74, 78, 68, 73, 32, 100, 97, 116, 97, 32, 115, 111, 117, 114, 99, 101, 32, 111, 114, 32, 119, 104, 101, 110, 13, 10, 35, 32, 117, 115, 105, 110, 103, 32, 97, 32, 74, 68, 66, 67, 32, 100, 114, 105, 118, 101, 114, 32, 116, 104, 97, 116, 32, 100, 111, 101, 115, 32, 110, 111, 116, 32, 105, 109, 112, 108, 101, 109, 101, 110, 116, 32, 116, 104, 101, 32, 74, 68, 66, 67, 32, 52, 46, 48, 32, 65, 80, 73, 13, 10, 35, 32, 40, 115, 112, 101, 99, 105, 102, 105, 99, 97, 108, 108, 121, 32, 97, 117, 116, 111, 109, 97, 116, 105, 99, 32, 114, 101, 103, 105, 115, 116, 114, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 41, 46, 13, 10, 35, 100, 114, 105, 118, 101, 114, 108, 105, 115, 116, 61, 13, 10, 13, 10, 35, 32, 102, 111, 114, 32, 102, 108, 117, 115, 104, 105], 2)]
```

So, no UPDATE is generated.

You can run my test case to see for yourself and compare to yours. Try debugging and see why the UPDATE is generated. Maybe it's not from the same entity that your persisting but from some other entity that you are silently modifying.

Comment: I didn't find a reason, but I found how to fix it - Lombok @Data generates equals, hashCode and toString methods and content should be excluded there, otherwise, I have an additional update statement

Comment: hm I was wrong, it's still reproducible. As I see ( (SelfDirtinessTracker) entity ).$$_hibernate_hasDirtyAttributes() returns true in DefaultFlushEntityEventListener line 486 and persister.resolveAttributeIndexes( ( (SelfDirtinessTracker) entity ).$$_hibernate_getDirtyAttributes() ) returns all fields are dirty and then hibernate thinks that update is necessary and scheduleUpdate( event ). I can't debug what is inside of $$_hibernate_getDirtyAttributes

Comment: Try without BE for dirty tracking as you only need it for lazy attributes.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean without BE (back-end? I didn't get it)

Comment: BE - bytecode enhancement. You just switched all flags to true in the Maven plugin.

Comment: all flags are true - I see update, all flags are false - I see update, remove plugin at all - no update :(

Comment: Just set the `enableLazyInitialization` to true and leave the other flags to `false`, and check during flush to see what's modified and triggers the flush.

Comment: I've updated post description because it's too long for a comment. Please, take a look

Comment: The Maven Plugin you posted here only has the `enableLazyInitialization` set to true. Yet, the presence of getDirtyAttributes suggests that you also activated `enableDirtyTracking`. Therefore, it's not really clear what you are doing. Try to replicate it with these test case templates: in.relation.to/2016/01/14/hibernate-jpa-test-case-template/ and if you can open a Jora issue.